# How to remove this this image Background in nextjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

[image]

This image is added but when it is rendered in *Nextjs* it automatically adds the extra content.

```
<div className="flex flex-col items-start justify-start rounded-3xl p-4 bg-boxi w-1/3">
  <div className="mb-4">
    <Image
      src={ProfilePic}
      alt=""
      className="w-1/2 h-auto hover:drop-shadow-image"
    />
  </div>
  <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-start">
    <p className="text-lg font-semibold text-light mb-1">------</p>
    <p className="text-base font-medium text-light mb-1">-------</p>
    <p className="text-sm font-medium text-light">example@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code inside the `div`, I need only the image not the extra square content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Next/Image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

> This next/image component uses browser native lazy loading

It's good practice for *SEO* and built to prevent *[CLS](https://web.dev/cls/) (Cumulative Layout Shift)* so its needs to be provided explicit [width](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#width:%7E:text=config.js.-,width,-The%20width%20property) and [height](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#width:%7E:text=fill%20property.-,height,-The%20height%20property) properties for layout management. Example:

```
<Image
    src={ProfilePic}
    alt=""
    width={500}
    height={500}
    className="w-1/2 h-auto hover:drop-shadow-image"
/>
```

Alternatively, another approach for this case is to lift these size properties to their container. Example

```
<div class="container relative h-10 w-10">
    <Image
        src={ProfilePic}
        alt=""
        fill
        size"30vw" 
        className="object-contain hover:drop-shadow-image"
    />
</div>
```

For more on this approach [fill](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#width:%7E:text=passing%20a%20prop.-,fill,-A%20boolean%20that) and [sizes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#width:%7E:text=object%2Dposition-,sizes,-A%20string%20that).

In your case, the layout can render out may be based on other higher containers of the `html` component you provided, which have explicit size properties. So you might change to those approaches above for clean layout management.